# Rename LAS files using python

Tags: python

I have a bunch of LAS files that have been delivered with different naming conventions. I want to rename the files to all have the same uniform naming - based on the easting and northing coordinates of each tiles centroid. I have generated a text file with the old and new names, and am trying to piece together a python script - but am running into this error

Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\LASTools\Test\ReName_Files.py", line 64, in newName = newList[indexOldName] NameError: name 'indexOldName' is not defined

here's the script... I am very new to python and so this could take me hours of research and trial and error (it already has)...

```
import os

folder = "C:\Test\"

lookupTable = open(folder + "LookupTable.txt")

tableList = lookupTable.readlines() lookupTable.close()

old = "TIFF" new = "TILE"

newTable = [] for line in tableList: newLine = line.strip()
newerLine = newLine.strip(",")
newestLine = newerLine.strip("'")
almostFinalLine = newestLine.replace('"',"")
finalLine = almostFinalLine.split(",") newTable.append(finalLine)

header = newTable[0] 
indexOld = header.index(old) - 1 
indexNew = header.index(new) - 1

oldList = [] 
newList = [] 
for item in newTable: 
if item != newTable[0]: 
valueOld = item[indexOld] 
valueNew = item[indexNew] 
oldList.append(valueOld) 
newList.append(valueNew)

for file in os.listdir(folder): 
nameAndExt = os.path.splitext(file) 
oldName = nameAndExt[0] 
extension = nameAndExt[1] 


if oldName in oldList: 
indexOldName = oldList.index(oldName)

newName = newList[indexOldName]

os.rename(folder + oldName + extension, folder + newName + extension)
```

Comment: You have an escaped `"` in the `folder` assignment, so your whole code is a string. You have several other syntax errors - please ensure your code here matches what you're running.

Comment: Please fix your code to have one command per line, and fix your indentation as well, which is very important in Python.

Comment: @jonrsharpe a raw literal still won't fix it - you can't have "\" be the last character of a string.

Comment: @MattDMo good point well made.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from your code not being correctly formatted and indented, the interpreter struggles at the line

```py
newName = newList[indexOldName]
```

The variable `indexOldName` is only defined if `oldName in oldList` was true beforehand. Otherwise it is not assigned and you can't use it to index `newList`.

So probably only you know what `newName` should be if `oldName` is not in `oldList`.

---

**Edit:**

To rename a number of files using a lookup table, the following approach should suffice:

```
import os

with open('lookup.txt') as f:
    table = f.read().strip().split('\n')

for line in table:
    names = line.split()
    os.rename(names[0], names[1])
```

Explanation:

- To read a file you should use the `with open(...) as` pattern. This ensures that the file will be closed after leaving this scope.
- To read the whole file at once you can use `read()`.
- The function `strip()` removes trailing line breaks if there are any.
- Finally the file content is `split` into single lines.
- The `for` loop iterates over all lines.
- A single line is `split` into two parts. Note that by default `split` splits the string at whitespaces. If your filenames contain spaces, you'll need to slightly modify this approach.
- Now we can `rename` the old file `names[0]` to `names[1]`.

Comment: I am using a subset of files (1 through 20) and I can get the script to rename file 20 correctly with the new naming convention - but it wont loop. I am not sure what function I should be using to force the script to loop through and rename each file from a text file list.

Comment: @jkoro: It's really difficult to debug and improve your code with such a poor formatting. But it's probably easier anyway to write such a small tool from scratch. So I edited my answer and provide a short algorithm that should solve your problem. (Please, study the code and all relevant functions and modify if necessary.)